# "zsh: command not found: create-react-app" for macOS High Sierra

Tags: npm, path, create-react-app, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I ran `npm install -g create-react-app` in my ohmyzsh terminal. The package was successfully installed.

When I use the command `create-react-app react-app`, I receive the error message `zsh: command not found: create`.

I know this error has to do with ohmyzsh and more specifically my PATH to the command but I am unsure what to write for the path.

My current PATH (.zshrc) looks like this:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/steven/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Paths I have tried appending include:

`:/usr/local/bin`
`:usr/local/bin/npm`
`:/usr/local/bin/create-react-app`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` to my `.zshrc` file.

I am now able to create react applications using the `create-react-app <app-name>` command!